# How to change Time zone Name from UTC to Uhr in <lightning-formatted-date-time>

Tags: lightning-web-components

`formatted-date-time` tag in lwc with Time zone UTC.
and out put is coming like 'Montag, 25. November 19, 09:00 UTC', now i want to change UTC to Uhr(German time zone). Is it possible to change time zone in LWC
Tried to give different time zone codes in Timezone attribute but it is not accepting other that UTC. Pleas some one help on this.

```
<lightning-formatted-date-time value={part.Schedule__r.Scheduledate__c} key={part.Id}
                              year="2-digit" month="long" day="2-digit" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" time-zone="UTC"
                              time-zone-name="short" weekday="long"></lightning-formatted-date-time>
```

Comment: whats the user locale?

Comment: Also can you try by removing timezone attribute `time-zone="UTC"`

Comment: I tried removing time-zone time showing with out UTC but i want Uhr along with time

Comment: User locale is German

Answer (score 0):

the component uses IANA timezones, as mentioned in the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/specification) 
setting the value to `"Europe/Berlin"` will display it as `GMT+1`.